# Why were the Harkonnen risking using a lasgun to shoot down Idaho's ornithopter?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

Were the Harkonnen using lasguns in the new Dune movie to try and shoot down Duncan?

It looked like they were shooting lasguns at Duncan as he escaped at one point in the movie. Wouldn't this create an unhappy situation (the destruction of the two ships), or was Duncan's shield somehow deactivated?

I'm assuming this was just an oversight in regards to them not addressing the conflict of the weapons in the movie, and the value of having him flying all around with stuff blowing up, but at the same time maybe I am misremembering something about these mechanics.

Comment: Because they’re just not quite as good a shot with javelins as the Night King is?

Comment: canon..........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idaho's 'thopter is hit by a missile, evidently overloading (or disabling) the shield.

[image]

You see the shield flickering and then apparently failing a few seconds later.

[image]

It would appear that our lasgunner saw this shield failure and decided that it was worth the risk of shooting him down with a lasgun.

Comment: I think the lasgun was firing from the ship, not the ground.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- - You're not wrong

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was a quick scene. Makes his escape that much more dangerous if his shield was down.